# Azure: get user email by principal id

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I have the following code to retrieve the IAM (access control) list of a resource group:

```
const authorizationManagement = require('azure-arm-authorization');
this.client = new authorizationManagement(credentials, subscriptionId);
var iam = await this.client.roleAssignments.listForResourceGroup(rgName);
```

However the results are all UUIDs, such as:

> id:"/subscriptions/de8abfb7-b22b-3c95-8e00-a1a8219e0d98/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/c5f2db94-98c3-3671-8092-fc33d8a474d7"
>   name:"c5f2db94-98c3-3671-8092-fc33d8a474d7"
>   principalId:"53a71af7-c241-34e1-b77b-e98151ca6b3f"
>   roleDefinitionId:"/subscriptions/de8abfb7-b22b-3c95-8e00-a1a8219e0d98/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b23988ac-5180-32a0-ab88-20f7682dd23c"
>   scope:"/subscriptions/de8abfb7-b22b-3c95-8e00-a1a8219e0d98"
>   type:"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"

I only need the principals (users) and their roles. I know how to [get the role by role ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-authorization/roledefinitions?view=azure-node-latest), but don't know how to get the user by principal ID.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-graph/users?view=azure-node-latest#get-string--object- The object id should be the principal ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for this method: [get(string, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-graph/users?view=azure-node-latest#get-string--object-).

```
function get(upnOrObjectId: string, options?: Object)
```

The `object ID` should be the `principal ID`, it returns the [User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-graph/user?view=azure-node-latest) what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any chance you can solve this problem too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049755/azure-graph-throws-access-token-missing-or-malformed